# Array to a String conversion

Tags: php

Não sei como resolver esse problema:

**Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.19-0\apache2\htdocs\casamento\noivosDAO.php on line 12**

**arquivo DAO:**

```
function insereNoivos ($noivos) {

  $query = "insert into noivos (nome1, sobrenome1, email, nome2, sobrenome2,
            telefone , rua, numero, cep, cidade, foto) values ('{$noivos->getNome1()}', '{$noivos->getSobrenome1()}', '{$noivos->getEmail()}', '{$noivos->getNome2()}','{$noivos->getSobrenome2()}', {$noivos->getTelefone()}, '{$noivos->getRua()}', '{$noivos->getNumero()}', '{$noivos->getCep()}', '{$noivos->getCidade()}', {$noivos->getFoto()})";

  return mysqli_query($this->conexao, $query);
}
```

**arquivo Adiciona:**

```
<?php
$noivos = new Noivos();
$noivos->setNome1($_POST["nome1"]) ;
$noivos->setSobrenome1($_POST["sobrenome1"]);
$noivos->setEmail($_POST["email"]);
$noivos->setNome2($_POST["nome2"]);
$noivos->setSobrenome2($_POST["sobrenome2"]);
$noivos->setTelefone($_POST["telefone"]);
$noivos->setRua($_POST["rua"]);
$noivos->setNumero($_POST["numero"]);
$noivos->setCep($_POST["cep"]);
$noivos->setCidade($_POST["cidade"]);
$noivos->setFoto($_FILES["foto"]);
```

Comment: $_FILES["foto"] é um array, se você tiver tentando armazená-lo direto no banco este é o erro. Caso seja isso mesmo, leia mais na documentação como armazenar corretamente os dados do arquivo.

Comment: Mellhor vc armazenar a foto numa pasta. o nome da pasta poderia ser o ID do usuario. Ai no banco vc guarda apenas o nome do arquivo

Comment: obrigado anderson vou ver a documentação.

Comment: Obrigado Israel, eu estou tentando fazer isso mesmo, a pasta é img e ela vai armazenar as fotos com uma extensão do nome no BD.